# Why does the cout in push function display the argument instead of rear->value and front->value?

Tags: c++, memory-management, g++, cout

This code takes data from a file and inserts into a queue.Besides, it does some other things but that are not to be concerned for errors..
It is to be noted that

> I have well-debugged the code

and yet unable to figure out why the contents of the queue are not being updated(or if updated, not displayed properly)
Also the main is displaying garbage values of queue

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<stdio.h>
    using namespace std;
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    struct node
    {
        struct node *next;
        char *value;
    }*front,*rear;
    struct node * createnode(char *val)
    {
        struct node *new1=new node;
        new1->next=NULL;
        new1->value=val;
        return new1;
    }
    void push(char *val) //This function should display "rear->value" and "front->value" but instead it is displaying "val"
    {
        if(front && rear)
        cout<<"Push called->"<<rear->value<<"->"<<front->value<<" -> "<<val<<endl;
        struct node *new1=createnode(val);
        if(front==NULL)
        {
            rear=new1;
            front=new1;
            cout<<"Created a node 1 -> "<<rear->value<<"->"<<front->value<<" -> "<<val<<"\n";
        }
        else
        {
            rear->next=new1;
            rear=rear->next;
            cout<<"created a node 2 -> "<<rear->value<<"->"<<front->value<<" -> "<<val<<"\n";
        }
    }                           
    char *pop()
    {
        cout<<"Pop called\n";
        char *ch;
        if(front==NULL)
            return NULL;
        else if(front==rear)
        {
            ch=front->value;
            front=NULL;
            rear=NULL;
            return ch;
        }
        else
        {
            ch=front->value;
            front=front->next;
            return ch;
        }
    }
    void scanitall()
    {
        cout<<"scanitall called\n";
        string line;
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("outputproject.txt");
        while(getline(infile,line))
        {
            char line1[100];
            strncpy(line1, line.c_str(), sizeof(line1));
            line1[sizeof(line1) - 1] = 0;   
            push(line1);
        }
        infile.close();
    }
    void processit(char *abc)
    {
        // cout<<"PRocess it called\n";
        outfile.open("outputproject.txt",ios::app);
        if(!outfile)
            cout<<"Error file not opened!";
        int i,len,flag=0;
        len=strlen(abc);
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(abc[i]=='*' && abc[i+1]=='*' && flag==0)
                {
                    flag=1;
                    i+=2;
                }

            if(abc[i]=='*' && abc[i+1]=='*' && flag==1)
            {
                outfile<<endl;
                flag=0;
                i+=2;
            }

            if(flag==1)
                outfile<<abc[i];
        }
        outfile.close();
    }
    void display(char *line)
    {
        // cout<<"display called\n";
        ifstream infile;
        string line2;
        char ch;
        infile.open(line);
        if(!infile)
            cout<<"File not opened!  ";
        while(getline(infile,line2))
        {
            cout<<line2;
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        infile.close();
    }
    void openallfiles()
    {
        // cout<<"openallfiles called\n";
        string line;
        char line1[100];
        ifstream infile;
        infile.open("outputproject.txt");
        while(getline(infile,line))
        {
            strncpy(line1, line.c_str(), sizeof(line1));
            line1[sizeof(line1) - 1] = 0;
            display(line1);
        }
        infile.close();
    }
    int main()
    {
        front=NULL;
        rear=NULL;
        scanitall();
        cout<<front->value<<"  Test\n";
        cout<<"Previously scanned contents are: \n";
        struct node *temp=new node;
        temp=front;
        if(!front)
            cout<<"memory error!\n";
        while(front)
        {
            cout<<pop()<<" -> ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        ifstream infile;
        string line;
        char line1[100];
        infile.open("inputproject.txt");
        while(getline(infile,line))
        {
            strncpy(line1, line.c_str(), sizeof(line1));
            line1[sizeof(line1) - 1] = 0;
            processit(line1);
        }
        infile.close();
        openallfiles();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: @NathanOliver Respected sir,I have well debugged the code already. I think there is some other issue

Comment: Try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might be able to locate the bug in the process, and find a fix for it too.

Comment: _it does some other things but that are not to be concerned for errors_ Then take them out. It'll narrow down the code we need to look at.

Comment: For us to confirm you have some well debugged error, we probably need input and expected output example.